# How to create only the field_for object in a nested form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nested-forms

I have a nested form where users can create any amount of products (`<%= f.fields_for :products do |product| %>`) and at the same time also create a location (`nested_form_for @location`) to put those products. But instead, what i want is users to select a location and only be allowed to create the products. I don't want to create the locations at all on this form. The form also should not give a location per product but only one location for all of them.

**How would you make the form select a location and create products only ?**

This form creates both the location and X amount of products:

```
<%= nested_form_for @location, :validate => true  do |f| %>
      # This will turn into selecting of predefined locations and not creating
      # the location as you see below this line
    <%= f.label :business_name, "Business Name" %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :business_name %>

    <%= f.label :address %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :address %>

    <%= f.label :phone_number, "Phone Number" %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :phone_number %>

    <%= f.label :website %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :website %>
  </div>

  <%= f.fields_for :products do |product| %>
        <%= product.label :name %>:<br>
        <%= product.text_field :name %> 

        <%= product.label :price %>:<br>
        <%= product.text_field :price %>

    <%= product.link_to_remove "Remove" %> # Removes a product field

  <% end %>
  </div>
  <p><%= f.link_to_add "Add Product", :products %></p> # Ajax add product field

    <div class="actions">
       <%= f.submit %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Can you clear up your question?  I'm not sure what your last sentence is asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want users to choose from a list of locations, and then add products to that location.  These locations are predefined somewhere (I'm getting in your `db_seed`) in your application.  Assuming those two things, then the question to your answer is just have a normal `form_for @product` and inside your form you will have a `select` with the option objects being the location where they users can choose.

```
<%= form_for @product do |p| %>
    <%= p.label :name %>:<br>
    <%= p.text_field :name %> 

    <%= p.label :price %>:<br>
    <%= p.text_field :price %>

    <%= select :product, :location_id, Location.all.collect {|l| [ l.business_name, l.id ] } %>
<% end %>
```

and in your controller you can just get the location with `params[:product][:location_id]` to retrieve the location the user selected and do your normal database stuff.  Hopefully that's clear enough for you.

If you want to create more than one product at a time, you need to use a `form_tag` and generate your own helpers to add/remove products.  This is more difficult but creates a better user experience.

Comment: But doesn't the following code above only add a location per product? i want only one location to all of the products on the form.

Comment: No it doesn't.  The select will only create a `select` tag in which you have reference to.  It's more for telling your controller which Location the user actually selected.  Like I said in the post, you probably seeded your db with some Locations already, and I also assume that your product has a location_id column so you know which Location the product belongs to.  But the point is that having the select tag won't actually create a new Location, especially since the tag is NOT bound to the form object (ie. @product), so you are free to use `params[:product][:location_id]` however you like :)

Comment: That's pretty much correct, i actually have users make locations by using my locations/new route and they then add products and select a location from a drop-down list in the products/new route.

Comment: @product = Product.new(params[:product][:location_id]) is what i have in my create action and all of my fields bring up errors so it doesn't let me create it.